# android activity to load the old activity instead of creating new instance of that old activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In My application there are three activities A, B and C and i have kept two buttons in every activity (Previous and Next button) so that user can move from one activity to another. Suppose User is in activity B and user wants to navigate to Activity A.

Here my problem is.. I need to load the old activity instead of creating new instance of Activity A.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `finish` on the current activity and the previous one will be shown automatically.

Comment: while calling finish(), the current activity gets destroyed.. Later i will be using that activity again..

Comment: There is no way to go back to the same instance of a previous activity without finishing the current one. You should go back to the previous one by calling finish and then re-create your next one when you need it again. Learn the Activity Lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your intent with the flag "BROUGHT TO FRONT"

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It is not possible to bring an activity to the front. You can ONLY finish the current activity to reveal the previous one.

Comment: Got it, @Kuffs.
@user3016075, in this case, I suggest you to save preferences about your Activity, then load it in the `onCreate(Bundle ...)` or `onResume(...)` of your Activity.